# Handler not assigned to KoGrid's filter field (Knockout + jQuery)

Tags: jquery, grid, knockout.js

I'm trying to customize [KoGrid](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/KoGrid/)'s filter so that I could filter the column with date data based on "from-to" logic (an example of KoGrid with filters can be found [here](http://ericmbarnard.github.com/KoGrid/examples/Complex-Server-Side-Paging.html)). What I wanted is to display a dialog, containing From and To inputs with Datepicker, when one clicks on the appropriate filter field.

```
var vm = {
            filterInfo: ko.observable(),
            myObsArray: arr
        };
        ko.applyBindings(vm); 
...
$("div.kgheadercell.col5").on("click", "input", function (event) {               
   $("#popup").dialog("open");
});
```

This however seems to be not working properly, i.e. the dialog is not being displayed once I click on the text field. However, if I try to input the last bit of the code in Chrome's console, the handler is correctly bound and the dialog appears once I click on the text field.

However, if I try

```
$("body").on("click", "input", function (event) {               
 $("#popup").dialog("open");
});
```

this successfully adds handler as I'm able to see the dialog when I click on any (obviously) text field.

Is there something happening after this code so that it removes or changes the handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KoGrid uses templates internally to manage the layout of the grid. It is possible that either:

- the grid hasn't finished rendering by the time you are trying to attach 'click' handlers to the header fields
- the template for the headers has re-rendered effectively removing your click handlers

An option you have is to use a custom header template. This is not documented in KoGrid, yet, but the functionality is there. You can use a click binding on the `<input>` element used as a filter box and manually set its value:

http://jsfiddle.net/ericbarnard/hCQ7r/1/

Look at how I've wired up the `doSomething` function on the viewModel to be called by clicking the filter `<input>` (after you open the filter row)

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the case. In fact, I was able to solve this by adding `attr: {id: \'filterInput\'+ $data.colIndex }` to the header cell template and then `$("body").on('click', '#filterInput5', function() {$("#popup").dialog("open");});` in `$(document).ready`